# How can I make a Standard User a Local Administrator from within PowerShell?

Tags: windows, security, powershell, scripting, uac

I'm writing a small PowerShell script launched from a batch file which will change a Standard User (when logged in) to a Local Administrator. It needs to be fully automated, and I know the given machine's Admin credentials. I figured that I would begin by passing the Admin credentials, but I'm having trouble getting around the Password prompt (since it requires user action). So far I have this.

```
 Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential "Domain\Username" -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList "Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb runAs"
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('Windows PowerShell Credential Request')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('SuperSecret')
```

Sendkeys isn't working as far as I can tell, and neither does `-Password` when I try to pass it as an argument. I'm not sure if I should pursue this method or if there is other logic that will let me assume a Local Administrator without being prompted to begin with. Also, this will be run on more than one machine, however the credentials are constant since they will all be on the same network.

Comment: You cannot bypass the UAC prompt, and this is by design. (Think about it: If this were possible, then malware would already be doing it.)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart has a point. You can get around the password prompt by creating a PSCredential object, and passing that to the `-Credential` parameter, but it will still pop up a UAC (User Access Control) dialog.

Comment: This question is so common that I wrote the following: [You cannot bypass the UAC prompt](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/21afa490-a74e-4052-8c34-e997cdc593b3/).